# Как писать запросы к апи в контакте

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Пытаюсь разобраться с vkapi, не могу понять как строить запросы например для получения списка аудиозаписей. Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример того как сделать запрос на получение списка аудиозаписей в результате поиска по названию. Там же можно будет запустить песню. В моем случае запускается первая песня в списке.

Описание фрагмента кода по памяти:

1. Создаем объект VKRequest для запроса.
2. Передаем ему, что за запрос будем делать и параметры - имя трека и константа (к сожалению забыл, что она делает).
3. Выполняем запрос и ставим ему слушателя.
4. В ответ приходит response и выполняется метод onComplete (есть еще несколько других методов на разные случаи, например, ошибка).
5. Парсим полученный JSON в модель для трека и у нас выходит список песен.
6. Выбираем первый элемент со списка (как самый лучший вариант).
7. Моя реализация проигрывания песни.

   ```
   public void searchTrack(String trackName) {
   VKRequest searchSongRequest =
           new VKRequest("audio.search", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.Q, trackName));
   searchSongRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
           super.onComplete(response);
           ArrayList<VkTrack> trackList = VkTrack.parseJSON(response.responseString);
           String song;

           if (trackList != null) {
               song = trackList.get(0).getArtist() + " - " + trackList.get(0).getTitle();
               AppData.sSongUrl = trackList.get(0).getUrl();
               Log.d(TracksSearcher.class.getSimpleName(), song);
               Log.d(TracksSearcher.class.getSimpleName(), AppData.sSongUrl);
           } else {
               Log.e(TracksSearcher.class.getSimpleName(), "trackList is null");
           }

           AppData.sAudioPlayer.play(mContext, AppData.sSongUrl);
           AppData.isSongPlayed = true;
       }
   });
   ```

   }

Comment: Можно не много расписать действия?

Comment: Я добавил описание.